# Convert NULL to empty string - Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, uniqueidentifier

Using SQL Server 2005 how do I get the below statement or rather the output as i want it to be.

```
SELECT Id   'PatientId',
       ISNULL(ParentId,'')  'ParentId'
FROM Patients
```

ParenId is a `uniqueidentifier` that allows `NULL`, but seems that query optimizer tries to also convert `''` back to `uniqueidentifier` for the rows where `ParentId = NULL`.As the title says that's the exact error info the query runner throws at my face!!

- How do i get the server to return empty string for `ParentId = NULL`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
SELECT Id   'PatientId',
       ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),ParentId),'')  'ParentId'
FROM Patients
```

[`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) always tries to return a result that has the *same* data type as the type of its first argument. So, if you want the result to be a string (`varchar`), you'd best make sure that's the type of the first argument.

---

[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) is usually a better function to use than `ISNULL`, since it considers *all* argument data types and applies appropriate [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/f4c804ab-ed3f-43b1-a024-c9ac6944b66b%28v=sql.105%29) rules to determine the final resulting data type. Unfortunately, in this case, `uniqueidentifier` has higher precedence than `varchar`, so that doesn't help.

(It's also generally preferred because it extends to more than two arguments)

Comment: thank you for giving more than wanted. I learnt a lot more from your answer Will mark it as answered in 4 minutes Greetz

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried 'COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(50),ParentId),'')' and 'ISSNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),ParentId),'')' and I'm still getting a zero instead of an empty cell. My ParentId is smallint.

Comment: Also tried ISNULL(CAST(ParentId as VARCHAR(50)),'') and COALESCE(CAST(ParentId as VARCHAR(50)),'')

Comment: @bteague - `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` are for dealing with *nulls*. Not *zeroes*. If you want a *zero* to become an empty string, you're probably looking for a `CASE` expression. Bear in mind though that if you want one outcome to be the empty string, you need to ensure that all possible results from the `CASE` are also strings. (Since e.g. an `int` *can't* contain an empty string)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My datapoint was smallint, when i tried to convert the null to an empty string I was getting a zero and I did not want zero's. ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),ParentID),'') was correct. My query was a series of 3 queries joined by union all and I only converted this field in the first block of code. The end result was zero's. Since the format of the first block of code typically carries (i thought) the format through the rest of that column in the query I expected it would have thrown an error rather than ignoring my varchar conversion. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9):

```
Select ID, IsNull(Cast(ParentID as varchar(max)),'') from Patients
```

This is needed because field ParentID is not varchar/nvarchar type. This will do the trick:

```
Select ID, IsNull(ParentID,'') from Patients
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to `CAST` the `ParentId` as an `nvarchar`, so that the output is always the same data type.

```
SELECT Id   'PatientId',
       ISNULL(CAST(ParentId as nvarchar(100)),'')  'ParentId'
FROM Patients
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Sql Server 2012: string concatenation function [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) converts to string implicitly. Therefore, another option is

```sql
SELECT Id AS 'PatientId',
       CONCAT(ParentId,'') AS 'ParentId'
FROM Patients
```

`CONCAT` converts `null` values to empty strings.

Some will consider this hacky, because it merely exploits a side effect of a function while the function itself isn't required for the task in hand.